# How to get Row Data from the table referenced by the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, subquery, where-clause

I am trying to select all notes that have a status of completed.
Notes are stored in there own table where we have a note status history table with a foreign key relationship by noteId. How can I get the data from the table referenced in the WHERE clause (t2) to that I do not have to loop again through the results just to get the data for CompletedBy.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   t1.NoteId,
   t2.CompletedBy-- error
FROM
   Note t1 
WHERE
   EXISTS 
   (
      SELECT
         TOP 1 * 
      FROM
         NoteStatus t2 
      WHERE
         t1.NoteId = t2.NoteId 
         AND t2.Completed = 1 
   )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want a lateral join:

```
select n.noteId, ns.completedBy
from note n
cross apply (
    select top (1) *
    from notestatus ns
    where ns.noteId = n.noteId and ns.completed = 1
) ns
```

You could get the same result with a correlated subquery - but the lateral join gives you the opportunity to return more columns fro the `notestatus` table, if you ever need to.

`distinct` does not seem to make sense, so I removed it - you can add it back if that's really needed for some reason you did not explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an explicit `join` or -- more simply -- a lateral join:

```
SELECT n.NoteId, ns.CompletedBy-- error
FROM Note n CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 ns.* 
      FROM NoteStatus ns 
      WHERE ns.NoteId = n.NoteId AND
            ns.Completed = 1 
     );
```

I'm not sure why you would need `SELECT DISTINCT`, so I removed it.  A column called `NoteId` sure seems like the primary key in a table calld `Note`.